# Convert String to JSON object in GWT (JSNI)

Tags: javascript, json, gwt, jsni

How to convert a string to a JSON object that I'll use inside JSNI?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [gwt core JsonUtils](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsonUtils.html) which has a safeEval method for the string. You should define a JavaScript Overlay Object for use with the result or you could work with the object in JSNI as you seem to want to.

Comment: Thanks! I resolved this using JSON.parse()  inside JSNI

Answer (score 4):

This is a copy-paste way to do it:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JsonUtils;
import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONArray;
import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject;

...

JSONObject data = new JSONObject(JsonUtils.safeEval(jsonString));
JSONArray array = data.get("anArray").isArray();
JSONObject obj = data.get("anObject").isObject();
```